# Set text in TextView in in-active fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have managed to get an actionbar with tabs, but when I click a button, a text should be set in both Fragments. If I try this it will crash the app, because only one of the Fragments is loaded. Is there a way I could set the text in both fragments?

Comment: can you post your code so we can check it

Comment: Please add your code to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution comes to my mind is that you may save the the text's value to a preference and then load the preference from second tab.something like this:

```
//save the value in your first fragment to the preferences
        prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("sampletext", "Your text value");
            editor.commit();

//get the value in your second fragment
prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());
prefs.getString("sampletext");
```

The second and dirty but fast solution would be to define a public static variable in your first fragment and access that variable in your second fragment.This method will be applicable only if your first fragment is not destroyed when switched to second one.

Answer (score 0):

If the fragment isn't loaded, then you should save off the text somewhere so that when the fragment is loaded, it can (while instantiating the text views), set the text view to the appropriate value.  (eg in the fragment's onActivityCreated() call, ask for the text to use)